# C# and XML can't select the good node's value

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file containing data for several people (this file is populated through a web-service, but I don't think it's important). At some point of the program, I need to iterate through all the people in the file.

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(res.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("nm", res.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlNodeList nodeListRes = res.SelectNodes("//nm:Resources", mgr);
for (int i = 0; i <= nodeListRes.Count-1; i++)
{

    XmlNode nodeRes = nodeListRes.Item(i);
    XmlNode nodeTest = nodeRes.SelectSingleNode("//nm:RES_NAME",mgr);

}
```

**nodeListRes** contains only the resources (aka the people) of my xml file. And I want to iterate through all this people and get specific information (in this example, the name). **nodeRes** works indeed (it changes with each iteration of the for loop) but (and it's what I can't understand) **nodeTest** is **always** related with the first resource of my xml file !

Here's the file for example (with dummy data)

```
<ResourceDataSet xmlns="namespace">
  <Resources>
    <RES_UID>blabla1</RES_UID>
    <RES_NAME>blabla1</RES_NAME>
    <RES_PHONETICS>blabla1</RES_PHONETICS>
    <WRES_EMAIL>blabla1</WRES_EMAIL>
    <RES_CODE>blabla1</RES_CODE>
    <RES_GROUP>blabla1</RES_GROUP>
    <RES_HIRE_DATE>blabla1</RES_HIRE_DATE>
    <RES_COST_CENTER>blabla1</RES_COST_CENTER>
    <BaseCalendarUniqueId>blabla1</BaseCalendarUniqueId>
  </Resources>
  <Resources>
    <RES_UID>blabla2</RES_UID>
    <RES_NAME>blabla2</RES_NAME>
    <RES_PHONETICS>blabla2</RES_PHONETICS>
    <WRES_EMAIL>blabla2</WRES_EMAIL>
    <RES_CODE>blabla2</RES_CODE>
    <RES_GROUP>blabla2</RES_GROUP>
    <RES_HIRE_DATE>blabla2</RES_HIRE_DATE>
    <RES_COST_CENTER>blabla2</RES_COST_CENTER>
    <BaseCalendarUniqueId>blabla2</BaseCalendarUniqueId>
  </Resources>
</ResourceDataSet>
```

And, in my code, in the second iteration of the for loop **nodeRes** will contain the data "blabla2" (verified with the debugger) but **nodeTest** will contain "blabla1". And it's really obscure to me !

Please help ! (If the question is not comprehensible enough tell me, English isn't my native language)

Comment: I think you should use the XNODE class 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx
It is much easier to handle.

Comment: Hum yes I could, but I'd need a lot of refactoring. I think I will try this this afternoon, but I'm always looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the //

```
XmlNode nodeTest = nodeRes.SelectSingleNode("//nm:RES_NAME",mgr);
```

should be

```
XmlNode nodeTest = nodeRes.SelectSingleNode("nm:RES_NAME",mgr);
```

// stands for "anywhere in the xml document"

Comment: Indeed, it works. It's why I hate xml, it's too precise for me ! But It works, thanks. I just have a question : nodeTest is supposed to select a single node in nodeRes, and nodeRes only contains **one** resource (I verified) so why the hell nodeTest selects a node who isn't even in nodeRes ? It's too complicated for me, I think

Answer (score 0):

Other possible way is by adding single point (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath query to indicate that the query is relative to current node :

```
XmlNode nodeTest = nodeRes.SelectSingleNode(".//nm:RES_NAME", mgr);
```

Or better yet, since `RES_NAME` is direct child of `Resources` use single slash :

```
XmlNode nodeTest = nodeRes.SelectSingleNode("./nm:RES_NAME", mgr);
```

Without the point (`.`) mentioned above, the engine will search from root node instead of current node, then return first node meets the criteria.